# Updating two different tables in one SQL statement

Tags: sql, updating

```
UPDATE `Order`
SET Order_Cost ='17.88' 
WHERE Order_Cost ='16.89'
UNION 
UPDATE `BagelCard`
SET BagelPoints = '50',Discount = True
WHERE BagelPoints ='45';
```

This is my sql code for upodating the value in two different table . Is it right ? or what sql command i  shoud use for updating value in two different tables.

Answer (score 4):

`UNION` is used for `SELECT` queries.  If you want to run two updates, you can use two separate queries:

```
UPDATE `Order`
    SET Order_Cost = '17.88' 
    WHERE Order_Cost = '16.89';

UPDATE `BagelCard`
    SET BagelPoints = '50',
        Discount = True
    WHERE BagelPoints = '45';
```

If your values are numeric than I would suggest dropping the single quotes.  Also decimal numbers such as prices should be stored as decimals/numerics rather than floats.

I should note that MySQL *does* allow you to update two tables in one statement.  You can use `JOIN`.  In this case, it doesn't really make sense because the tables do not seem to be related to each other:

```
UPDATE `Order` o CROSS JOIN
       `BagelCard` bc
    SET o.Order_Cost = '17.88',
        bc.BagelPoints = '50',
        bc.Discount = True
    WHERE o.Order_Cost = '16.89' AND bc.BagelPoints = '45';
```

Comment: I didn't know that MySQL allows an update of two tables using a CROSS JOIN, it's good to know. However in my opinion, this single query could be  hard to read and easy to misunderstand. I prefer to separate the queries for better readability.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano . . . I much prefer using two separate queries (the first solution), particularly in this case.  However, on re-reading the question, it seems the OP was asking for a single command to update multiple tables.

Comment: Yes, the OP was asking for a single command of course. I don't have anything against your answer (I added an upvote, by the way). Mine was only a comment about the readability of the single command query. :-)